# How to replace pip install's removed install-option with its config-settings equivalent?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, python-packaging

I was previously installing a custom Python package with a C++ extension successfully on Windows by using this:

```
    pip install --install-option=build_ext --install-option="--library-dirs=/path/to/lib" *.zip
```

But then pip upgraded to 23.1 and its `--install-option` flag [was removed](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11358). Irq3000 provided a helpful comment [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11358#issuecomment-1493207214) about how to use `--config-settings` instead, but I still can't get it to work. My current version is:

```
    pip install --config-settings="--install-option=build_ext" --config-settings="--install-option=--library-dirs=/path/to/lib" *.zip
```

The build output in Windows shows that `/path/to/lib` is missing from the list of directories looked at by the linker (i.e., there's no `/LIBPATH:/path/to/lib` argument for Windows' `link.exe`).

Does anyone know how to pass in the library directory via `--config-settings`?

UPDATE: I posted about this on pip's issue tracker too - https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12010

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way to pass in `--install-option` values directly via `--config-settings` (or equally, `--config-setting`). Instead, as a workaround, I set the `LIB` environment variable in Windows to add the required `/LIBPATH` flag for the linker ([Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/libpath-additional-libpath)). So:

```
set LIB=/path/to/lib
pip install *.zip
```

Presumably, if this were Linux instead of Windows you would use the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable instead to point at your library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Posting answer here from your original [github issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12010#issuecomment-1532704837):

Instead of:
pip install --config-settings="--install-option=blah"

Use:
pip install --config-settings="--build-option=blah"

It might look like this:

pip install --config-settings="--build-option=build_ext" --config-settings="--build-option=--library-dirs=/path/to/lib" *.zip

Comment: Thanks! However I'm pretty sure I tried that and it didn't work for me. Hence I ended up setting the `LIB` environment variable instead.